# Use variable as Type

Tags: c#

Is it possible to make such code work?:

```
    private List<Type> Models = new List<Type>()
    {
        typeof(LineModel), typeof(LineDirectionModel), typeof(BusStopTimeModel), typeof(BusStopNameModel)
    };

    foreach (Type model in Models) // in code of my method
    {
        Connection.CreateTable<model>(); // error: 'model' is a variable but is used like a type
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: yes but there is no easy way like this . for performance reason i suggest you write all code for all types you need. i think there is way with reflection but it would be slow and not easy to implement.

Comment: You'd have to use reflection's `MakeGenericMethod`.  There's probably a better way to do what you want.  But yes you could.

Comment: `CreateTable<typeof(model)>` should work I think.

Comment: @SamedTarıkÇETİN No, it won't work. typeof(model) doesn't actually get resolved until runtime, but the compiler needs to know about the exact type at compile time.

Comment: @PoweredByOrange I see. Thanks for info.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You won't be able to use the variable as a generic type using the conventional syntax (`CreateTable<model>`). Without knowing what `CreateTable` does, you have two options:

1. Instead of making `CreateTable` a generic method, have it take the type as a parameter:

   ```
   public static void CreateTable(Type modelType)
   {
   }
   ```
2. Use Reflection to dynamically invoke the generic method using the desired type:

   ```
   var methodInfo = typeof (Connection).GetMethod("CreateTable");
   foreach (Type model in Models)
   {
       var genericMethod = methodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(model);
       genericMethod.Invoke(null, null); // If the method is static OR
       // genericMethod.Invoke(instanceOfConnection, null); if it's not static
   }
   ```

Note that the reflection way would be slower since the method info won't be resolved until runtime.

Comment: Exactly because it is slower you should move the `typeof (Connection).GetMethod("CreateTable")` outside the `foreach` and only call the `MakeGenericMethod` and the `Invoke` inside.

Comment: @xanatos Good point, revised.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this,

```
private List<Type> Models = new List<Type>()
{
    typeof(LineModel), typeof(LineDirectionModel), typeof(BusStopTimeModel), typeof(BusStopNameModel)
};

void SomeMethod()
{
  MethodInfo genericFunction =Connection.GetType().GetMethod("CreateTable");

  foreach (Type model in Models) 
  {
    MethodInfo realFunction = genericFunction.MakeGenericMethod(model);
    var ret = realFunction.Invoke(Connection, new object[] {  });
  }
}
```