# Use variable like type / Generic method

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, types, refactoring

I am trying to refactor below two methods

#### method 1

```
public void DoSomething(Bus a, string str)
{
   var temp = new List<Bus>();
   ...
}
```

#### method 2

```
public void DoSomething(Car a, string str)
{
   var temp = new List<Car>();
   ...
}
```

Below doesn't work, and gives **'a is a variable, but used like a type'** error. In addition to that, I can't even imagine how to call this method / what to put in the first parameter.

```
public void DoSomething<T>(T a, string str)
{
   var temp = new List<a>();
   ...
}

DoSomething<Bus>(Bus, "str");
DoSomething<Car>(Car, "str");
```

1. Other posts suggest to use `MakeGenericMethod`. Is this the only way? [Use variable as Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35804075/use-variable-as-type)
2. If I want those methods to return `List<T>` (Car / Bus) instead of `void`, how can I use #1 solution with Generics?

**Update**
As I left in the comments -> @ChetanRanpariya, How to call this method, then? DoSomething(?, ?);

Comment: You should do `var temp = new List<T>();`

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya, How to call this method, then? DoSomething<Bus>(?, ?);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You used `a` (the instance) instead of the actual type `T`

```
public void DoSomething<T>(T a, string str)
{
   var temp = new List<T>(); // you need to use T here, it's the actual type
}

...

DoSomething<Bus>(myBus, "str");
DoSomething<Car>(myCar, "str");
```

---

### Additional Resources

[Generics (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/)

### Update

[41686d6564](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8967612/41686d6564) made an interesting point

It's hard to tell if you are actually trying to pass the type into the methods parameter:

```
DoSomething<Bus>(whatYouPassInHereWouldNeedToBeAnInstanceNotAtype,"str");`
```

If you don't need to use the instance, there is no need to pass it in. Just use the generic parameter

```
public void DoSomething<T>(string str)

...

DoSomething<Bus>("str");
```

Comment: Also, shouldn't the passed _argument_ be an instance instead of the type? E.g., `DoSomething<Bus>(someBus, "str");`? If OP doesn't really need an instance, then the first parameter can be dropped altogether and the method signature would be `public void DoSomething<T>(string str)`.

Comment: @41686d6564 yeah it does look they are passing a type in the parameter. I just put it down to "Who know what casing style kids use these days" type of thing

Comment: It's not just the casing. The actual type name is `Bus` (based on the usage of `List<Bus>` and `DoSomething<Bus>`). It would've been a casing issue if it was something like `DoSomething<Bus>(MyBus,..)` as opposed to `myBus`.

Comment: @41686d6564 yeah i know what you mean, it still could be an instance `Bus` as well, Its just really hard to know whats going on here without the op commenting. Ie is it a property of type `Bus` named `Bus`.

Comment: @41686d6564 i tried to make the point obvious, but i have run out of time, if you think you can be a bit more elegant in the wording, feel free to edit.

Comment: The updated part is the what I want. Thank you Michael and @41686d6564

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you either have a typo or the list is not defined correctly

```cs
public void DoSomething<T>(T a, string str)
{
   // Incorrect
   var temp = new List<a>();

   // Correct
   var temp = new List<T>();

   // ...
}

DoSomething<Bus>(Bus, "str");
DoSomething<Car>(Car, "str");
```

Maybe this helps...