# how to copy a baseclass to an endclass without reference?

Tags: c#, winforms, inheritance, polymorphism

I am trying to write a method that can copy an existing class into a new one, but without a reference to the source class.
There are many samples out there, but in my case the source and target objects are defined as a baseclass while they are created as an endclass.

My classes are like this

```
// my baseclass
public partial class ModelBase
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public RowStatus Status { get; set; }
}

// one of my endclasses
public class ModelUser: BaseClasses.ModelBase
{
    public int? UserID { get; set; }

    public string UserFirst { get; set; }

    public string UserLastname { get; set; }
}

// and there are many more that derive from ModelBase off course...
```

What I would like is that in a Base Form (where all other forms will derive from) I can copy an existing model into a new one, without a reference to the existing one.
So I tried to do this using serializing/deserializing, which works well, but only if you know the exact type, and in my BaseForm I do not have the exact type yet, there I work with an instance declared as ModelBase, but created in a derived form as ModelUser for example.

In other words, I have a base form like this

```
public partial class FormMVBaseDetail
{
    protected ModelBase model = null;
    protected ModelBase _originalModel = null;
    ...

    private void FormMVBaseDetail_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _originalModel = CloneModel(model);
    }

    protected ModelBase CloneModel(ModelBase model)
    {
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ModelBase>(json);
    }
}

public partial class FormMVBaseUser : FormMVBaseDetail
{
    model = new ModelUser();
    ...
    // somewhere in the code some properties of model could change...

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Now I would like that _originalModel is an exact copy of model
        // So _originalModel should be of type ModelUser, not ModelBase
        // How to achieve that without additional code in FormMBaseUser ?
     
        if (_originalModel.UserFirst != model.UserFirst)
        { // do something }
    }
}
```

The first attempt is this

```
public ModelBase CloneModel(ModelBase model)
{
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ModelBase>(json);
}
```

this has the problem that, allthough the parameter `model` is created as `new ModelUser()`  the deserialize will make it a `ModelBase` which only has one public property, the Status.

If I would do this, then it would work, but only for `ModelUser`

```
public ModelBase CloneModel(ModelBase model)
{
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ModelUser>(json);
}
```

This is not usefull in a baseform.
So the next thing I tried is this

```
public object CloneModel(ModelBase model)
{
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(json);
}
```

The idea was to use it like this

```
ModelBase _originalModel = null;
_originalModel = (ModelBase)CloneModel(CurrentModel);
```

but for some reason it always deserializes as `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject` in stead of `object`, so this also does not works for me.

How could I achieve this ?

I have read this links, but they did not get me any further

[How do I use reflection to call a generic method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-do-i-use-reflection-to-call-a-generic-method)
[Passing just a type as a parameter in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10955579/passing-just-a-type-as-a-parameter-in-c-sharp)
[How can I use an expression tree to call a generic method when the Type is only known at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433436/how-can-i-use-an-expression-tree-to-call-a-generic-method-when-the-type-is-only)
[Use variable as Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35804075/use-variable-as-type)

Comment: Do you know the concrete type in runtime?
For same from install will it be always same concrete type?

Comment: @Ygalbel no, it can be any class that derives from ModelBase

Comment: You could make the base class generic:

public partial class FormMVBaseDetail<T> where T : ModelBase
{
    public T CloneModel(T model)
    {
       var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
       return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
    }
}

Comment: Might be tedious (and I might miss something obvious) but why not simply write copy constructors in your endclasses that take the baseclass as argument and perform deep copy of the properties?

Comment: @AndrewMcClement That is also in the links I wrote at the bottom of my question, but I can't get it to compile/work. Maybe an example of how to do this in this case ?

Comment: @RolandDeschain Do you have an example of how to do that ? If I have 100 classes derived from ModelBase I don't want to write 100 methods to do this off course

Comment: Yeah, just realized my idea doesn't make much sense in this scenario, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the non-generic version of `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject()`

It take the string in first parameter and the type in second one.

So your clone function will be like this:

```
public object CloneModel(ModelBase model)
{
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, model.GetType());
}
```

Comment: Compile fine for me

Comment: Sorry I had a typo, works for me also now, thanks you

Answer (score 1):

The generic version of Ygalbel's answer would be this:

```
public partial class FormMVBaseDetail<T> where T : ModelBase
{
    protected T _model;
    protected T _originalModel;

    public T CloneModel(T model)
    {
       var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
       return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
    }
}
```

Whether you want the base class to be generic will depend on your needs.

Usage:

```
public partial class FormMVBaseUser : FormMVBaseDetail<ModelUser>
{
    _model = new ModelUser();
    // Other code as before
```

Comment: How do I call this method for my situation ?

Comment: Sorry, I'll add an example derived class

Comment: Though this might work (have not tested yet) I like the answer of Ygalbel more. It seems more simple to me. Maybe someone can explain the differences between these 2 approaches and which would be the better one ? I'll up this answer anyway off course

Comment: @GuidoG The most obvious difference to highlight is that using generics (`<T>`) allows the derived types to be used everywhere.  No casting from `object` to `ModelBase` is needed when cloning; no casting from `ModelBase` to `ModelUser` is needed within the derived class `FormMVBaseUser`.